# PyQt5 : ImportError : DLL load failed : The specified module cannot be found

Tags: python, dll, pyqt5

To explain my situation :

- I have the python version 3.7.9
- I downloaded PyQt5 with pip

```
pip install pyqt5
```

- So i have the 5.15.4 version on pyqt5
  But when I run my script I have this error :
  from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
  ImportError: DLL load failed:  The specified module cannot be found.

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a solution.
I fully uninstalled python 3.7.9
I downloaded python 3.10.7
Then pyqt5 and that worked !

Maybe it was just about the python version.